# Visual Studio Code marks each line of all files red

Tags: visual-studio-code, ember.js

I am having the latest version of Visual Studio code.

```
Version: 1.69.2 (user setup)
Commit: 3b889b090b5ad5793f524b5d1d39fda662b96a2a
Date: 2022-07-18T16:12:52.460Z
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
```

I am using Ember.js projects. Whenever I am opening any file, it is marking each and every line as red.

> Native JS classes should be used instead of classic classes
> eslintember/no-classic-classes

I tried uninstall/ install VS Code (also I completely uninstalled and then installed again) but nothing helpled

Asap I try install my usual extensions it starts giving trouble.

Comment: which extension gives the trouble, do you have this problem with all extensions disabled, looks like a linter error message, disable linting for your language or disable that particular test

Comment: You could disable the eslint ember extension or the specific rule (eslintember/no-classic-classes) you want to ignore

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you have some legacy files, and eslint is highlighting that. The only way to remove the red marks is to:

- remove the eslint extension from vs code
- disable the eslint extension in vs code
- disable the rule via adding `"ember/no-classic-classes": "off"` to your eslint config's rules section
- use a todo system, such as https://github.com/mansona/lint-to-the-future
- upgrade your code